# Unable to tag SCM maven release plugin goal execution from docker container

Tags: git, docker, maven, bamboo, maven-release-plugin

We have used Source code checkout task in bamboo and for executing maven goals we used docker container so we mounted build-dir from agent to docker using docker volume mount.

We have used maven-release plugin so that Jar should get autoincremented and pushed to nexus.

While executing mvn release:prepare git is not able to tag its able to do git commit but while executing git tag step its unable to do it.

But even if we are mounting entire build-dir we are facing below error:
error: object directory /opt/bamboo_agent/xml-data/build-dir/_git-repositories-cache/db16.........../.git/objects does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates
build   21-Dec-2020 04:07:31    [ERROR] fatal: bad object type.
build   21-Dec-2020 04:07:31    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
build   21-Dec-2020 04:07:31    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project : Unable to tag SCM

Please help us in this as we are troubleshooting this from many days.

Thank you.

Comment: I think the problem is related to this: `.git/objects does not` because it looks like the `.git` directory is not being existing within the docker container...

Comment: Here we have mounted entire folder on docker container.

Comment: The error message says something different. Have you checked the content of the container? Is the git repo correctly cloned or is that a shallow clone?  I would suggest to play those steps... manually step by step and see where the issue is located. Furthermore I see git_repositories_cache? Is that the real location? looks strange to me.. ? Have you check the content before running release plugin... just use a shell script (instead of mvn release..)  to keep the container running for debugging purposes ?

Comment: Command used in bamboo script task docker run --name mycontainer  -i \
     -v "/opt/bamboo_agent/xml-data/build-dir/":/usr/src/mymaven \
     -w /usr/src/mymaven/<BambooBuildKey>/ <docker image registry path> mvn release:clean release:prepare -B   after volume mounting folder git_repositories_cache is present in /usr/src/maven dir and pom.xml and other source code with .git folder is present in /usr/src/mymaven/<BambooBuildKey> within docker container.